# How can I make 3D graphics in java?

Tags: java, graphics, 3d

Do I have to make another class file for this?

I just want to be able to create a 3D person holding a sword, that I will later be able to manipulate during a battle.

Comment: I am guessing that down-vote could be caused by fact that your question doesn't show research effort and it is kind of unclear since "*Do I have to make another class file for this?*" is not very precise, since we don't even know what class files you already have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java 8 includes the 2D & 3D scenegraph API named *JavaFX* which can do in a simple way what you're looking for: 2D and 3D objects in a Java scenegraph. Please take a look at the JavaFX tutorial here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm

For your question the Tutorial's 2nd headline would be interesting:

*Graphics: Getting Started with JavaFX 3D Graphics*

Also, in the official Java8 demo ZIP archive with sources and examples, next to the JDK and JRE downloads, there's a FX demo named "3DViewer". With it you can import various 3D file formats (OBJ and Maya files), display them and export them into Java's native FX scenegraph XML format. You then can load such XML 3d object files directly into your Java application and show it in your FX scenegraph.

It's all very well done, pure Java i.e. no external libraries, and easy enough even for 3D beginners like me.

Good luck with your 3D experiments.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, with the nice OpenSource 3D editor and renderer Blender you can create own 3d models, export them as a OBJ file (maybe you've to activate this exporter first in the Blender settings, I can't remember) and then use the mentioned Java8 demo named _3DViewer_ to load the OBJ file and export it to a FX "native" XML file, so that you can use your Blender models in your Java application.